# The namespace or module is not defined

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I am trying to work through the [getting started docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode) for F#
Visual Studio Code shows an error
 [image: here]

If I hover my mouse over the red squiggle I see the error message

```
The Namespace or module ClassLibraryDemo is not defined"
```

Here is the code for ClassLibaryDemo.fs

```
namespace ClassLibraryDemo

module PigLatin =
    let toPigLatin (word: string) =
        let isVowel (c: char) =
            match c with
            | 'a' | 'e' | 'i' |'o' |'u'
            | 'A' | 'E' | 'I' | 'O' | 'U' -> true
            |_ -> false

        if isVowel word.[0] then
            word + "yay"
        else
            word.[1..] + string(word.[0]) + "ay"
```

Comment: when you actually `#load ClassLibraryDemo` do you get the feedback in `FSI: [Loading c:\Users\*****\Documents\Source\SO2017\SO180207\TestModule.fs]
namespace FSI_0002.TestModule
  val testFunc : unit -> unit`, it looks like it can't see the file (maybe).

Comment: @s952163 I updated the question to show the interactive terminal.
You are right about it not being able to see the file.  I had spelled the name incorrectly as ClassLibaryDemo.  Would you like to add your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the feedback in FSI when you execute `#load ClassLibraryDemo.fs`. You should see something like this:

```
FSI: [Loading c:\Users\*****\Documents\Source\SO2017\SO180207\TestModule.fs] namespace FSI_0002.TestModule val testFunc : unit -> unit
```

Most probably FSI can't find your file, either because the file name is misspelt or the file is in another directory. There could be other possible causes of not being able to see a namespace, for example not restoring a project, or corrupted cache (this I haven't seen in a while).